# How to install the "BHOManager CLASS" add-on in IE

Tags: qtp

This "BHOManager CLASS" add-on is a supporting add-on to run QTP script on the IE browser.

The publisher of this add-on is Mercury Interactive Corp.

I have uninstalled the existing IE browser because of some issues in my machine and reinstalled it. And after this i cannot run the QTP script as the "BHOmanager Class" add-on is missing.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling QTP? That would be the best bet to get is working again. Free tip: When the installer tells you you have to restart your PC, respect that. Unlike other installers you can mess up when you don't do it with the QTP installer.

Comment: Thanks for the quickest reply, as i am working on a remote machine i cannot have admin rights to do that, and even if i have admin rights, its a risky process for me to uninstall the existing one and re installing this. Is there any other alternative to help with ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the re-install was the easiest option, but let's try this:
Can you see the BHOManager class in IE?

```
Go to IE > Tools > Manage Add-ons, make sure BHOManager class 
(Browser Helper Object) from Mercury Interative Corporation is 
enabled.
```

It is recommended to disable other add-ons, such as third-party toolbar, add- 
ons from anti-virus companies, etc. This is to make sure nothing is 
preventing QTP from hooking into the browser, but that is not the main problem in your case I think.

If this is all the case, you re-register the BHOManager again, but maybe you have not the correct rights.

```
Close IE and all iexplore.exe processes in the task manager
Close QTP (or restart your machine)
Go to Start > Run, unregister and register BHOManager.dll: 
    regsvr32 -u c:\WINDOWS\system32\BHOManager.dll 
    regsvr32 c:\WINDOWS\system32\BHOManager.dll
```

Comment: The above suggested solution worked, and after registering BHOManager.dll, the BHOManager Class add-on is available in IE browser. Thanks so much.

Comment: If this worked, you can mark this answer as Accepted Answer so others with the same problem searching on Stack Overflow can see that this is the correct solution.

Comment: And for 64bit, `regsvr32 -u "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\BHOManager.dll"` and `regsvr32 "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\BHOManager.dll"`