# HP UFT and BHOManager.DLL

Tags: hp-uft

Using HP UFT v11.53 Patch 5
The BHOManager.dll is not registered and of course not enabled on some of our test machines.

Can anyone tell me the purpose of the BHOManager.dll and problems may occur if it is not registered, installed, enabled, etc...

Comment: Any thoughts regarding the only answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

BHO stands for [Browser Helper Object](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_Helper_Object), UFT uses it in order to interact with the browser. UFT can control the browser partially without this dll but some operations require it such as `Browser("").Back`.

Comment: `Browser("").Navigate` is another key one that requires the extension to be enabled.

Comment: @Dave, yeah but who uses that? :)

Comment: I understand that the BHOManager helps the BROWSER object with methods such as Navigate, Forward, Back, Refresh, etc...
Is it only required for these methods of the BROWSER object?
Is there a definitive list of methods and/or properties that will or will not work without the BHOManager?

Comment: @paulrazz AFAIK it's the methods you listed but this is undocumented. From HP's prospective nit having the BHO is unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

This DLL is what allows the UFT runtime to control and drive the IE browser. BHO stands for [Browser Helper Object](https://blog.malwarebytes.com/threats/browser-hijack-objects-bhos/)

Please review this SO article for some ramifications and how to resolve them.
[Repercussions & Resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13586606/168617)